# Agilitookit - Loading data from the database in a form (Simple Edit Form)

Tags: atk4

In the next code I want to load data from the data base in to the from.  (Edit Form)

```
   $model = $this->add('Model_Partner');
   $model->addCondition('id','1');
   $form = $this->add('Form');
   $form->setModel($model);
   $form->addSubmit();
```

The form comes empty,
What is the probem?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In Agile Toolkit model can "load" one record at a time. By using Conditions you tighten the number of records it can potentially load. It will actually not produce any query.

```
$model->load(1);
$form->setModel($model);
```

this should be the correct approach. You do not need to set condition as load() takes care of that.